# Binding background color doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am trying to set background color of some icon via binding, but I'm probably missing something and don't know what.

The xaml:

```
<materialDesign:PackIcon x:Name="SaveIcon" Kind="ContentSave" 
                         Height="25" Width="25" Background="{Binding Background}" />
```

Code behind:

```
public Page6()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Background = "Red";
}

private string _background;
public string Background
{
    get
    {
        return _background;
    }

    set
    {
        _background = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName=null)
{
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

But this don't do nothing, I mean there is no background color.

Comment: I think this is because `Background` property is of type `Brush`, not `string`, but I can't test it right now

Comment: You should see binding errors in Output window during debugging.

Comment: there is no binding errors

Comment: plz post answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already `Brush Background` property in Control class. your `string Background` property hides base property, but binding `Background="{Binding Background}"` still picks up the base property.

You can remove `string Background` completely and use `Brush Background`,
or rename your new property.

```
public Page6()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    BackColor = "Red";
}

private string _background;
public string BackColor
{
        get
        {
            return _background;
        }

        set
        {
            _background = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
}
```

Change binding:

```
Background="{Binding BackColor}"
```

Comment: @PabloEscobar: Did you really bind to "BackColor"?

Answer (score 1):

change your Background property to

```
private SolidColorBrush _background;
public SolidColorBrush Background
{
    get
    {
        return _background;
    }

    set
    {
        _background = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

and change 
    `Background = "Red"`
to
    `Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);`